# Core Plot x-axis Labels Overlapping/CPTLabellingPolicyAutomatic Won't Show Dates

Tags: iphone, ios, core-plot

I have a Core Plot graph in an iPhone app and want to limit the number of labels on the x-axis. Currently I am using the CPTLabelingPolicyNone and showing NSDates (displaying like: Jan 2) on the x-axis without a problem, other than the fact that once there are more than 10 or so entries, they start overlapping each other. I really want there to be more like 7 or 8 entries max on the x-axis.

I have read that I can use CPTAxisLabelingPolicyAutomatic and set the preferredNumberOfTicks to what I want. The problem is when I do that, I don't get dates on my x-axis anymore, I get decimal numbers like 0.0, 0.1, etc. I'm not an expert at this, so I'm not really sure why I am not getting dates anymore. Could anyone shed some insight on this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `CPTTimeFormatter`:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
dateFormatter.dateStyle = kCFDateFormatterShortStyle;
CPTTimeFormatter *timeFormatter = [[[CPTTimeFormatter alloc] initWithDateFormatter:dateFormatter] autorelease];
timeFormatter.referenceDate = refDate;
axis.labelFormatter = timeFormatter;
```

Several of the Core Plot example apps demonstrate this feature including the Plot Gallery and DatePlot.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. I have had a look at these projects and see where the timeFormatter is used, however, I'm still not sure how to implement it in my case. The user is making entries on different dates, could be a week apart or a month apart in terms of the entries. How do I use the CPTTimeFormatter to give my graph the right date entries? I am doing that without the timeFormatter right now, but I imagine I have to use this to use the automatic labelling policy?

Comment: The automatic labeling might not work very well if the date range varies enough to be days, weeks, or months. It is not aware that the values on the axis are being treated as dates. If you'll always format the values as days (and not weeks and/or months) it will probably be ok. If you're going to switch the label format for different ranges, the auto labels probably won't be where you want them.

Comment: Thanks very much Eric. In the end I wrote an algorithm to calculate how many labels should fit on the plot. Since I'm not zooming in or out, it seems to work well. Appreciate the help.